# cql cassandra - need to have a column with values -1, 0, 1

Tags: cassandra, cql

what data type would be ideal for representing the values -1, 0, +1 in  cassandra CQL? Any answers greatly appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: Avoid micro optimizations like this, it looks like an int, treat it as such, avoid unnecessary serialisation and application level confusion.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why not int (32 bits)? if you are really really worried about size you can stretch it and use a single byte blob but I guess this is stretching it too much.

Here is a link you might want to take a look at:

[Data Types](http://www.datastax.com/documentation/cql/3.1/cql/cql_reference/cql_data_types_c.html)

Answer (score 0):

You could just use a boolean and insert true, false or null.